# 1 day and 1-day, which is the right one in this case?

Tags: hyphenation

From another question I understand that "1-day offer" is the way to go, but if I rephrase it a little bit:

1. The offer will last for 1 day
2. The offer will last for 2 days

Which one needs to be hyphenated if at all?

Comment: related **1.** [When-to-spell-out-numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/when-to-spell-out-numbers), **2** [When should I spell the word as opposed to just using the number?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163564/when-i-use-numbers-when-should-i-spell-the-word-as-opposed-to-just-using-the-nu?rq=1) and **3.** [Why do English writers avoid explicit numerals?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/979/why-do-english-writers-avoid-explicit-numerals)

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA. My mistake was to limit my search to *cardinal numbers*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No hyphenation is needed in these cases; this is just 'normal' use of a cardinal number. You can compare this with something like "I see two apples."

Note that I have replaced "2" with "two". As noted in the comments, in most cases, it's customary to write out small numbers in full.

Comment: Right. Also, consistent with your apples example, most style guides that I'm familiar with favor "one day" and "two days" over "1 day" and "2 days"—at least in running text.

Comment: If I keep writing it like that, is it _least favorable_ or outright wrong to do so?

And for future reference - are there any cases where using "1 day" over "one day" is more favorable?

Comment: I'd say it is less favorable; in general, short numbers (1-20, 100, 1000) are written out in full. There's probably another question on EL&U which covers this.

Comment: Best to provide a link, or give a full answer in comments because...   numbers remain digits  in maths, and especially in addresses, e.g. 10 Downing Street, and often for ages: *a 5-year-old child*

Comment: Better still why not expand your answer and mention the "one day" vs "1 day"? Which one is possibly ambiguous without context? Which one is probably used in supermarkets: "two for one" or "2 for 1"?

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate, you should have searched first then answered :)